# JDBC connection not happening

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ubuntu, jdbc

Below is the code I used for jdbc connection

```
String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
String user= "kumar";
String pwd="ratiol";

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pwd)) {
    System.out.println("Database connected!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
}
```

but I got error as below-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
    at jdbcConnection.Jdbcdemo.main(Jdbcdemo.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at jdbcConnection.Jdbcdemo.main(Jdbcdemo.java:19)
```

Can you please tell me how can I get jdbc url?

I am using eclipse(mars) in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you have mysql jar files in your classpath?

Comment: Just load the driver first `class.forname( com.mysql.jdbc.driver )`

Comment: Just follow this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using netbeans, right click project -->properties -->libraries-->add library and select MySQL JDBC Driver

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wrote

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pwd)) {
    System.out.println("Database connected!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
}
```

it would be like this:

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    //registering the jdbc driver here, your string to use 
    //here depends on what driver you are using.
    Class.forName("something.jdbc.driver.YourFubarDriver");   
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pwd)
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Please check [Class.forName not more needed when using JDBC v.4](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html)

> Let's take a quick look at how we can use this new feature to load a
>   JDBC driver manager. The following listing shows the sample code that
>   we typically use to load the JDBC driver. Let's assume that we need to
>   connect to an Apache Derby database, since we will be using this in
>   the sample application explained later in the article:
>
> ```
>  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
>     Connection conn =
>         DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword);
> ```
>
> But in JDBC 4.0, we don't need the `Class.forName()` line. We can
>   simply call `getConnection()` to get the database connection.
>
> Note that this is for getting a database connection in stand-alone
>   mode. If you are using some type of database connection pool to manage
>   connections, then the code would be different.

There are plenty of reason for the exception `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql` like

1. Your JDBC URL can be wrong.
2. ClassPath/BuildPath/Lib folder missing the connector jar.
3. Driver Information is Wrong.

Comment: Your "corrected" code is outdated: using `Class.forName` is no longer necessary (which you even acknowledge with the text you quote), and the OP correctly used try-with-resources (assuming they don't want to do anything else with the connection), which your code undoes by removing the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

just add the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to the lib folder in you program files.

Comment: Would you please tell me where should I add that? Inside a notepad?

Answer (score -3):

Just load the driver first:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

Comment: Using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since Java 6 / JDBC 4 (+ a JDBC 4 compliant driver)